# Is it possible to change a Windows hostname (NetBIOS name) using a script?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scripting, automation, hostname

How can I change the hostname of a Windows server using a script?

Doing this on a Linux server is very straightforward (change a couple file entries, and run the `hostname` command), but I don't know how, or even if it's possible, to change a hostname on Windows in an automated fashion.

Specifically I'm looking for a way to do this on Windows 2008 R2, but a generic approach would be great, too.

I found this [technote](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;298593&sd=tech) for XP, but haven't tried it on a 2k8 machine - is it still valid?

The entire context is to be able to change a server's name post-deployment from a VMware template *without* using a Custom Specification.

Comment: Why is is you don't want to automate VM creation but do want to automate system names?

Comment: @Jim B - corporate restrictions on automatic system names

Comment: I'd love to hear more about that.  My usual problem is figuring out how to script in the corporate naming standard.  This is the first case I've ever heard of where a corporate naming standard is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @Jim B - the corporate naming standard is *not* "forbidden" - it's enforced - for the host *itself* .. the VM name may or may not be the same as the corporate naming standard

Comment: so why not have a scripted install uses the custom template (or IMHO use MDT and skip the templates alltogether)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you found is valid and the Best Practices way of configuring a Server Core install.

```
netdom renamecomputer localhost /NewName:FooBar
```

Works on remote machines too by changing `localhost` to something that allows Windows to resolve the remote computer. If a remote computer is specificed you'll need to supply credentials unless domain credentials or Windows Passthrough auth applies.

Specify creds with `/UserO username /PasswordO password` for local authentication
Use `/UserD username@domain.com /PasswordD password` for domain authentication.

`NetDom` is also the same utility used to scrip joining a computer to a domain, to manage DNS Alternate names (poorly conceived, don't use them), and a variety of other administrative tasks.